# Themes websites do not sync with system theme

Tags: gnome, themes, gui, 22.04

Themed websites like Youtube, Gmail, Github, Reddit, even Google Chrome settings have a theme, and one option is to match to system theme. I currently have Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome 42) set to Dark Theme, but websites and apps do not match it. Is there a way to fix this?